# How to enable code coverage in sonarcloud.io for c# project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have integrate SonarCloud to my open source project, but not getting code coverage report as it Quality Profiles is not pointing to c#.

Could anyone help me how to enable code coverage for C# project?

Sonar report is as below
https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=Amitpnk_Hexagonal-Architecture-ASP.NET-Core

Answer (score 0):

SonarCloud doesn't support automatic analysis for C# code. We need to take help of task runner, I preferred appveyor to run SonarScanner to analyzed my C# project

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-enable-code-coverage-in-sonarcloud-io-for-c-project/34359